# Using mutliple text formatting using lambda function in pandas dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I am trying to format a given string that contains alphabets, special characters, and numbers. My target is to remove everything except alphabets and space in the string. I am able to do it in multiple line of code that certainly does not look good. Can you help me reformat the blow line of codes so that I can do multiple formatting in online instead for 4- lines like below?

```
scholar['title_format'] = scholar['title'].map(lambda x: str(x)) #change the value to string

scholar['title_format'] = scholar['title_format'].map(lambda x: re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z ]', '', x)) #remove any special characters

scholar['title_format'] = scholar['title_format'].map(lambda x: re.sub(r'[0-9]', '', x)) #remove any numbers

scholar['title_format'] = scholar['title_format'].map(lambda x: x.lower()) #change it to lower case
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

```
scholar['title_format'] = scholar['title'].astype(str).str.lower() \
                                          .str.replace(r'[^a-z\s]*', '')
```

**UPDATE:**

```
scholar['title_format'] = scholar['title'].astype(str).str.lower() \
                                          .str.replace(r'[^a-z]*', '') \
                                          .map(lambda x: ''.join(sorted(x)))
```

Comment: This works in fine except that it does not remove the spaces. Also, when we remove spaces for sorting the letters I was using the following: 

scholar['title_format'] = scholar['title_format'].map(lambda x: ''.join(sorted(x)) #sort the alphabates

Is it possible to incorporate this as well??

Comment: @kunaldeep, you said: `My target is to remove everything except alphabets __and space__ in the string`...

Comment: Oh my bad..!! Actually, My full idea is to remove everything and sort the letters.

Comment: @kunaldeep, glad i could help :)